# Jest testing of Apollo Client GQL query

Tags: graphql, jestjs, apollo-client

Apollo Client lets you directly execute queries for example.

```
import { ApiClient } from './index'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export const query = (data) => ApiClient.query({
  query: gql`
    query {
      users (user:"${data.id}") {
      name
    }      
  }
`
})
  .then(data => { return data.data.users })
  .catch(e => { return e })
```

I was wondering if anyone had experience writing Jest tests for these.
All I've found is examples using `react-apollo` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to test your queries and mutations, I recommend testing that on the back end.

take a look at this article here: [Testing GraphQL](https://hackernoon.com/extensive-graphql-testing-57e8760f1c25)

Comment: That link seems dead now - and the links in web archive are broken too https://web.archive.org/web/20220817155428/https://hackernoon.com/extensive-graphql-testing-57e8760f1c25